# Shopify API - Add a form field to products page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I'm working on an app using rails with the shopify API, and was wondering if there is anyway to add a custom field to the products page in the admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add extra content to the Product page in the admin. What you can do is add a link to that page which takes you to an external page (your app) in order to make any changes.

Comment: Thanks, so i'd store their custom product fields data in my app's database?

Comment: Exactly. There's also the option of using [Metafields](http://api.shopify.com/metafield.html) to store the data if it makes sense.

Comment: Ahh I see, yes the Metafields will be just what I need, thanks!